# си после расчета функции на вывод я получаю значение -nan

Tags: c, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

при программировани на си столкнулся с проблеммой, есть простая программа, при определенных значениях b в переменную l присваивается значение -nan, как можно в дальнейшем проверить что в l находится значение -nan например через if

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double b,l;
        b = M_PI;
        l = sqrt(sqrt(pow(1,4)+4*pow(b,2)*pow(1,2))-pow(b,2)-pow(1,2));
        printf("%.7f", l);
}
```

Comment: Тут следует не наличие nan проверять, а удостоверяться, что аргумент `sqrt` имеет допустимый диапазон.

Comment: А зачем у вас вычисляется единица в разных степенях? Это же всегда единица.

Answer (score 3):

Разберем по кускам...

```
l = sqrt(sqrt(pow(1,4)+4*pow(b,2)*pow(1,2))-pow(b,2)-pow(1,2));
```

Имеем:

```
pow(1,4) == 1
pow(1,2) == 1
```

Итого  `sqrt(1+4*pow(b,2))` примерно равно 6,362265....

Затем минус пи в квадрате, минус 1... Итог — `-4.5...`

Еще раз: отрицательное значение.

И чему должен быть равен квадратный корень из него?

Может, вы что-то не то считаете? Очень смущают ваши `pow(1,2)`...

Ну, а проверить на то, не NaN ли получилось - просто: `isnan()`. Типа,

```
if (isnan(l))
    puts("Error");
else
    printf("%.7f", l);
```

Comment: спасибо, с функцией все норм там, у меня проблема была только с проверкой на nan